# Mysql LEFT JOIN on two parameters with one exact and one LIKE match on very large tables - performance

Tags: mysql

I have two tables of historical data - one (OldData) is 40,000 records from a datasource with partial/inaccurate data that I am trying to clean, the other (LookupData) is a definitive source of just over one million accurate records.

I am trying to enrich the first, smaller table with records from the larger one, and I can predict matching records by joining on surname and a numeric value known as the service number, but in the first table these numbers are often incomplete.

OldData (partial/inaccurate data) examples:

```
Surname | ServiceNumber
Smith | 12345
Jones | 9876
Brown | 234
```

LookupData examples:

```
Surname | ServiceNumber
SMITH | 12345
SMITH | 23456
JONES | 98765 
JONES | 19182
BROWN | T12345 
BROWN | 56789
```

Desired result:

```
OldData.Surname | OldData.ServiceNumber | LookupData.ServiceNumber
Smith | 12345 | 12345
Jones | 9876  | 98765
Brown | 234   | T12345
```

The current query that I have is

```
SELECT OldData.*,LookupData.ServiceNumber
FROM `OldData` 
LEFT JOIN `LookupData` 
ON lower(OldData.Surname) = lower(LookupData.Surname) 
AND LookupData.ServiceNumber like concat('%',OldData.ServiceNumber,'%')
```

but this never seems to complete

If I narrow it down to a single surname for testing, and add

```
WHERE OldData.Surname='Devlin'
```

I get the 47 rows from OldData and the accurate LookupData.ServiceNumber where any matches are found (and null where they aren't) but this query still takes 27 seconds on average.

I have indexes on both Surname fields and ServiceNumber fields.

If I'm seeking the impossible I'd at least like to know :) Thanks

Comment: MySQL index not work for query "like %..." and "function() = function()"

Comment: If LookupData Surname alway in uppercase, you can try change join condition query on LookupData.Surname = upper(OldData.Surname).

Comment: Bingo! I created a new column with upper(OldData.Surname) and just used that direct in the LIKE to avoid any transformation. With the where clause it returned 47 results in 0.02s and the full 42,000 records returned in 0.34s. If you can add that as an answer I'll be glad to accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the two `JOIN` conditions of your query.

```
lower(OldData.Surname) = lower(LookupData.Surname)
```

Using a function on both ends of the equality slows down the search. MySQL string searches are usually case-insensitive by default, unless you use [the `BINARY` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary). This condition can be rewritten as

```
OldData.Surname = LookupData.Surname
```

---

Second `JOIN` condition is :

```
LookupData.ServiceNumber like concat('%',OldData.ServiceNumber,'%')
```

`LIKE` is not good for performance, especially when there is a `%` at the beginning : because MySQL indexes are usually *ordered*, this causes a full scan to be triggered, because there is no way to find an optimized starting point for the search. In your sample data, it looks like you could remove the starting `%`.

Using `INSTR` will likely not improve performance.

You could try with a regexp, like :

```
LookupData.ServiceNumber REGEXP OldData.ServiceNumber
```

If you really need to search on both ends on large data, the way to go in MySQL is [Full-Text Search Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). This would require creating a `FULLTEXT` index on the service number columns (and possibly converting them from numeric to text), and then :

```
MATCH LookupData.ServiceNumber AGAINST OldData.ServiceNumber
```